# Action Bar menu - Submenu showing wrong items.

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My main file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_adhoc1"
                android:icon="@drawable/icon_custom"
                android:title="@string/menuitem2_3"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/cPanel1"
                android:icon="@drawable/icon_cpanel"
                android:title="@string/menuitem2_5"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/tutorial1"
                android:icon="@drawable/icon_tutorial"
                android:title="@string/menuitem2_4"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
  </menu>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that place three more options under the menu, however I get only one option under menu labelled as "Settings", clicking on this leads to the desired result of getting three options under the menu. Where am I going wrong, any hints?

Comment: What do you mean "under the menu"? If you don't to show the Settings just remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you nested a `<menu>` containing `<item>`s inside another `<item>`.

As per the [Menu documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml), this adds your second menu as a submenu of the parent item.

What it sounds like you are looking for is all the items being withing the same menu, like so:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_adhoc1"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_custom"
        android:title="@string/menuitem2_3"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/cPanel1"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_cpanel"
        android:title="@string/menuitem2_5"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/tutorial1"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_tutorial"
        android:title="@string/menuitem2_4"/>

</menu>
```